# Timeout on CPU usage?

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way, in SQL Server, to cause a batch to time out if its CPU usage exceeds some value specified in the batch?  I need this to occur at the batch, and not the connection level.

Comment: How exactly do you specify a batch? One command, or a "true" batch (what was sent from the client to the server for parsing, optimization and execution)?

Answer (score 1):

There has been a quick and dirty method in SQL Server for 20 plus years - you set the value of Query governor cost threshold to your arbitrary amount and then if the estimated cost of the execution plan exceeds that the query is rejected - I believe the end user receives some kind of error message but I haven't seen this enabled in the wild for a VERY long time so can't remember any details.

NB: more than just CPU costs is included [from the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-query-governor-cost-limit-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15) : CPU time, memory, and disk IO.